# Jquery Animation Problem

Tags: jquery, animation, colors

I wonder how I can fix this propabably easy problem.

Ive installed the color plugin for a smooth change of the backgroundcolor. So but when Im hovering over it a few times in a short amount of time, it'll repeat and repeat the animation like its a stack. 
How can I fix that? Any idea?

```
$("#page-bar > ul > li").mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#3c78a7"
                }),500;
            }).mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#333333"
                }),500;
            });
```

Comment: Code seems pretty good actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#page-bar > ul > li").mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#3c78a7"
                }),500;
            }).mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#333333"
                }),500;
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use *stop()* to stop the current animation for the element.
http://api.jquery.com/stop/